# PHP MVC question

Tags: php, model-view-controller

Given a `Controller` class and a `View` class, is it better for the controller to directly assign values to view properties or, is it better to assign values to properties in the controller and then copy those properties to the view when ready to display it?

**Example Model Class**

```
class Model
{
  public $propertyA;
  public $propertyB;
}
```

**Example Controller class:**

```
class Controller
{
  protected $view;
  protected $model;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->model = new Model();

    $this->view = new View();
    $this->prepareData();
    $this->initView();
  }

  protected function prepareData()
  {
    $this->model->propertyA = 'This is property A.';
    $this->model->propertyB = 'This is property B.';        
  }

  protected function initView()
  {
    $this->view->model = $this->model;
    $this->view->display();
  }
}
```

**Example View class:**

```
class View
{
  public $model;

  public function display()
  {
    echo "propertyA = $this->model->propertyA";
    echo "propertyB = $this->model->propertyB";
  }
}
```

**Sorry, I was tired. I do use a model, so please reconsider your answers with this in mind.**

Comment: Could you post a snippet of code to explain further ? Not sure what the difference is between the two.

Comment: Don't over-analyze your code. Either way is valid.

Comment: @Romain - I just posted an example of preparing the properties in the Controller class and then, when all is ready, copying it over to the View class. Is this a good idea, or should I just put data directly into the view when I get it and not hold copies in the Controller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data should only be in one place. If not when things get complicated it is hard to sync the different places you have the data. In MVC you have a model and that is where the data should be. Pass the Model into the View and have the view display that.

Here is a simple explanation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93View%E2%80%93Controller  or here for those that do not like Wikipedia: http://ootips.org/mvc-pattern.html

The model can be as simple as a class with the properties in it.

Comment: what happens if you replace/delete the view before it is executed?

Comment: Thanks, I am actually using a model in my setup. I should have added that to the example.

Comment: @Ben Rowe What do you mean ? The data is in the model, The controller would delete the old view and create a new one with the model.

Comment: Would +10 if I could.  *This is whole point of OOP:* to pass around an encapsulated object that has data and behavior attached, i.e. passing the model to the view so the view can use that data.  @Ben Rowe, the model is passed by reference.  If the view is deleted, nothing happens to the model.

Answer (score 2):

The view shouldn't be setting up variables unless they are related to the presentation. It's best to put static variables in a config file anyway.

> copy those properties to the view

Rather than setting variables in the view why don't you just construct the view with a reference to the controller. That should save you from writing a lot of boiler plate code.

```
Class Controller() {
  $this->something = 'abc';
  function __construct() {
    $this->display();
  }
  function display() {
    $this->view = new View($this);
  }
}

Class View() {

  function View(&$controller) {
    $this->controller = $controller;
    print $this->controller->something;
  }

}
```

**Edit:** I like Romain Hippeau's answer a lot more than my own. You should pass the model into the view.